# Why I Can't Get A Return Value To BAC?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>

<title>BAC Calculator</title>
```

//form for my html page. Not sure weather to use submit or just a button for this type. also if the return form is what is correct or not.

```
<form action="" onSubmit="return formbac()" id="formbac">
Weight:<input id="weight" name="weight1" type="number">
Beer:<input id="beer" name="beer1" type="number">
Wine:<input id="wine" name="wine1" type="number">
Shots:<input id="shots" name="shots1" type="number">
Time:<input id="time" name="time1" type="number">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate">
<hr>
BAC: <input type="" name="bac" id="BAC">

</form>

</head>

<body>
```

//Javascript code for calculations
I think this is correct but i could possibly be mixing code up with my calculations//

```
<script>
```

// Basic function

```
function formbac(){
//values
var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
var beer = document.getElementById("beer" * .54).value;
var wine = document.getElementById("wine" * .6).value;
var shots = document.getElementById("shots" * .6).value;
var time= document.getElementById("time").value;
var BAC = 0;
```

//trying to get my output of baclevels

```
// calculations
var BAC = ((beer + wine + shots * 7.5) / (weight * .68)) - (0.015 * time);

//decimal round
var BAC = math.round(bac*100)/100;

//output
var BAC = document.getElementById(BAC).value;

}
</script>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("shots" * .6).value` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Mathletics It should work for `<input id="NaN">` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output should be the other way around:

```
//output
document.getElementById('BAC').value = BAC;
```

Also, all the multiplications you're trying to perform inside `document.getElementById` should go outside. For example:

```
var beer = document.getElementById("beer").value  * .54;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line instead

```
document.getElementById("BAC").value = BAC; //notice "BAC" instead of BAC, you're trying to grab the element that doesn't exist
```

Comment: still am not able to get a return value

Comment: I was able to grab the element and display it in the text box but it only flashes then disappears. How do i get the element to stay within the BAC form box??

Answer (score 0):

```
// calculations
var BAC = ((beer + wine + shots * 7.5) / (weight * .68)) - (0.015 * time);

//decimal round
var BAC = math.round(bac*100)/100; //override above value 

//output
var BAC = document.getElementById(BAC).value; //override above value
```

As per your code your output will be the value of input control.